# Yup remove invalid fields from object?

Tags: yup

I have an array of objects I want to validate using `Yup`, and get rid of any fields in the object which do not pass the validation. Here is the `Yup` schema I built:

```
const schema = Yup.object().shape({
  id: Yup.string().nullable(false),
  country: Yup.string().trim().nullable(false),
  firstname: Yup.string().trim().nullable(false),
  lastname: Yup.string().trim().nullable(false),
  email: Yup.string().trim().nullable(false).email(),
  phoneNum: Yup.string()
    .trim()
    .test("phone", "", (value) => isPossiblePhoneNumber(`+1${value}`))
});

const schemaArr = Yup.array().of(schema);
```

I'm then calling this on my array of objects like this:

```
const sanitization = await schemaArr.cast(input, {
  abortEarly: false,
  stripUnknown: true
});
```

However, this doesn't remove the invalid fields. Does anyone know how I can accomplish such a thing?

**Here is my code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-pascal-8865e**